# Escape lower than (lt) greater than (gt) operators text version Velocity Template Languaga

Tags: velocity, vtl

I have the following statement in my `vtl` on line 36 :

`#if( !$util.isNullOrEmpty($ctx.args.filter.outstanding_amount.lt))`

I get an error:

```
Parse error on line 36:
....outstanding_amount.lt))      $util.qui
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'CONTENT', got '<'
```

I [read](http://people.apache.org/%7Ehenning/velocity/html/ch06.html) that `lt` and `gt` are a short versions of lower than and greater than operators.

How to make the parser understand `.lt` and `.gt` as identifiers and not logical operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ctx.args.filter.outstanding_amount.get('lt')
```

Comment: Also, I don't know why you referenced such an old version of the docs. Please use [the new version](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/vtl-reference.html#ifelseifelse-output-conditional-on-truth-of-statements).